# Replace string content with each others

Tags: python, replace

I have a string: 1x22x1x.
I need to replace all 1 to 2 and vice versa. So example line would be 2x11x2x. Just wondering how is it done. I tried

```
a = "1x22x1x"
b = a.replace('1', '2').replace('2', '1')
print b
```

output is 1x11x1x

Maybe i should forget about using replace..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a some temporary string as intermediate replacement:

```
b = a.replace('1', '@temp_replace@').replace('2', '1').replace('@temp_replace@', '2')
```

But this may fail, if your string already contains `@temp_replace@`. This technique is also described in [PEP 378](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0378/)

Comment: Yeah, it is almost fine. Output gave me `@temp_replacex11x@temp_replacex`. So still something needs to be done.

Comment: @Waldema. Are you sure you got that output? I got [correct output](http://ideone.com/IaGY13)

Comment: Positive, double checked.. :o Or am i just typoing?

Comment: @Waldema Did you do 3 replace? Check the demo on the link I posted in comment.

Comment: Oh dammit. It was me typoing. Sorry!

Comment: Wanted to thank you again. So I ended up using this despite of the other alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way using the `translate` method of a string:

```
>>> a = "1x22x1x"
>>> a.translate({ord('1'):'2', ord('2'):'1'})
'2x11x2x'
>>>
>>> # Just to explain
>>> help(str.translate)
Help on method_descriptor:

translate(...)
    S.translate(table) -> str

    Return a copy of the string S, where all characters have been mapped
    through the given translation table, which must be a mapping of
    Unicode ordinals to Unicode ordinals, strings, or None.
    Unmapped characters are left untouched. Characters mapped to None
    are deleted.

>>>
```

Note however that I wrote this for Python 3.x.  In 2.x, you will need to do this:

```
>>> from string import maketrans
>>> a = "1x22x1x"
>>> a.translate(maketrans('12', '21'))
'2x11x2x'
>>>
```

Finally, it is important to remember that the `translate` method is for interchanging characters with other characters.  If you want to interchange substrings, you should use the `replace` method as Rohit Jain demonstrated.

Comment: Would this work if we want to replace `abc` with `xyz` and `xyz` with `abc`?

Comment: This some how returns an error: TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Comment: @Waldema - Sorry about the delay--I had trouble recreating your error.  Eventually, I realized that you must be using Python 2.x because the error can only be made that way.  I edited my post to support 2.x.

Comment: Would be also cool to hear why i wasn't able to get this working.. Still learning Python but code above returns an error with me.. :S

Comment: Okokok! Now I understand! And yes I'm using Python 2.7.5 encouraged by the slow upgrading university world.. lol.. But anyway high five to all of you helped me out! =))

Answer (score 0):

If the "sources" are all one character, you can make a new string:

```
>>> a = "1x22x1x"
>>> replacements = {"1": "2", "2": "1"}
>>> ''.join(replacements.get(c,c) for c in a)
'2x11x2x'
```

IOW, make a new string using the `get` method which accepts a default parameter.  `somedict.get(c,c)` means something like `somedict[c] if c in somedict else c`, so if the character is in the `replacements` dictionary you use the associated value otherwise you simply use the character itself.